# How to refactor this simple class fields

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a very basic OOP question. I have two classes as follows

```
public class Class1 {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private List<String> field3; 
    // constructors 
}

public class Class2 {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private List<Object1> field3; 
    // constructors 
}
```

The only reason i had to create class2 was because the List in class1 can either be a List of Strings or a List of Object2. Is there a way to et rid of Class2, and have field3 behave as a List of String and also as a List of Object2.

I know i can do something like

```
public class Class1 {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private List<String> field3; 
    private List<Object1> field4; 

    // constructors which are initializing null to either field 3 or field 4
}
```

But the above doesnt seem clean, as an object instantiated with either list should not have any reference in it of the other List.

Comment: Generics........

Comment: `class Class1<T>` and `private List<T> field3;` should do it.

Comment: arghhhh why couldnt i think of this!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html):

```
public class Class1<TField3> {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private List<TField3> field3; 
    // constructors 
}

Class1<String> stringObj = new Class1<>();
```

Comment: I just cant believe why this didnt come to my mind!!